# If I have a window.open, do I lost my cookie?

Tags: java, javascript, web, struts2

can you help me to figure out what could be the problem? I have a page A and a page B.
I click a link in page A that opens page B by a "window.open". Moreover, page B is generated throught Velocity engine. Well, in page B when I click a button, an asyncronus cross-domain Ajax call starts but I get a 302 error, probably by SiteMinder. I think this is because with window.open I lost one cookie needed for this ajax call. Too bad, sources are a very mess, it's not mine, and I would figure out what's happening without try to understand all the code. Thanks you.

EDIT: Ok, after some tests, I see this: prolem is the fact that page B is generated and it hasn't all the struts stuff like session in it, so I have not that cookie. But I don't know to put that in the page.

Answer (score 0):

A 302 means that the page you requested is on another location, it's not necessarily an error. If the content of the redirected page is an error regarding something influenced by a cookie, then you could try using a [pixel](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1347585?hl=en). It will create a cookie for "website B" through "website A". Also make sure the cookie is not specific for a path or subdomain.

Comment: In the response I can see the location where I am redirected and in the url I see "smMakeCookie", so I think Site Minder get me a 302 because I haven't this cookie. Is correct for you? How could I fix this?